# How to output properly ( OOP )

Tags: php, templates, redirect, meta-tags

i'm new to OOP and stuck at this point :

so here is my code :

```
function url($type,$ownerid = NULL){
echo $this->hal_detail_people.'?type='.$type.'&id='.$ownerid;
}
```

when i do something like $alamat->url it works perfectly ,
but i want to create a redirect function that make use of that function above

```
redirek($alamat->url($_POST['type'],$_POST['ownerid']));
```

and this is the redirect function :

```
function redirek($alamat){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$alamat'>";
}
```

but it output the url first and then the rest , like `theurl.php<meta http blah blah` , so i'm wondering how to properly use it ? any help would really be appreciated . thanks

Comment: use `return` instead of `echo` -> `return $this->hal_detail_people.'?type='.$type.'&id='.$ownerid;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to do this is to `return` your data from the function and `echo` it in the main execution. This way you can do other things with the data your functions generate instead of immediately outputting it.

```
function url($type,$ownerid = NULL){
  return $this->hal_detail_people.'?type='.$type.'&id='.$ownerid;
}

function redirek($alamat){
  return "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$alamat'>";
}

echo redirek($alamat->url($_POST['type'],$_POST['ownerid']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use return in function:

```
function url($type,$ownerid = NULL){
    return $this->hal_detail_people.'?type='.$type.'&id='.$ownerid;
}
```